# OpenGLES in RosyWriter

Tags: ios, opengl-es, core-video

As an OpenGLES beginner, I have the following questions about some OpenGLES functions in Rosywriter.
RosyWriter is Apple official sample code. Here is the link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html

In

```
RosyWriterOpenGLRenderer::copyRenderedPixelBuffer:(CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBuffer
```

the author calls **CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage** to generate two **CVOpenGLESTexture**, srcTexture(from the input **CVPixelBufferRef** pixelBuffer) and dstTexture(from the output **CVPixelBufferRef** dstPixelBuffer, which is generated from **CVPixelBufferPool**).
Then the following code copies the content from srcTexture to dstTexture.

```
// Set up our destination pixel buffer as the framebuffer's render target.
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture( CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( dstTexture ), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName( dstTexture ) );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( dstTexture ), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName( dstTexture ), 0 );


// Render our source pixel buffer.
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1 );
glBindTexture( CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( srcTexture ), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName( srcTexture ) );
glUniform1i( _frame, 1 );

glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

glVertexAttribPointer( ATTRIB_VERTEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, squareVertices );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( ATTRIB_VERTEX );
glVertexAttribPointer( ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, textureVertices );
glEnableVertexAttribArray( ATTRIB_TEXTUREPOSITON );

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4 );

glBindTexture( CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( srcTexture ), 0 );
glBindTexture( CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( dstTexture ), 0 );

// Make sure that outstanding GL commands which render to the destination pixel buffer have been submitted.
// AVAssetWriter, AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer, and GL will block until the rendering is complete when sourcing from this pixel buffer.
glFlush();
```

My questions are
1. Does the change on **CVOpenGLESTexture** also apply on **CVPixelBufferRef**, which **CVOpenGLESTexture** is created from by calling **CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage**? I think so; otherwise how does the dstPixelBuffer get the content?

2. Does **glDrawArrays** draw the texture content to **GL_FRAMEBUFFER**? If so, how does OpenGLES know? And Is it because dstTexture attaches to **GL_FRAMEBUFFER**(by calling **glFramebufferTexture2D**), the content in **GL_FRAMEBUFFER** modified by **glDrawArrays** will also affect dstTexture?
3. In the end of code I post, the author calls

   ```
   glBindTexture( CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( srcTexture ), 0 );
   glBindTexture( CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( dstTexture ), 0 );
   ```

   what is the purpose?

Thank you so much for precious time on my questions. Please feel free to correct if any concept or terminology is wrong.